# Z3: Invalid bounded variables

Tags: python, z3, solver, z3py, first-order-logic

I am trying to see validity of a sentence in Z3 (Python), but I am getting the following message: `Invalid bounded variable(s)`

I copy here the steps I followed:

```
v, a, b, c, d, e = Ints('v a b c d e') 

lt_1 = (v == 4)
lt_2 = (v == 2)
lt_3 = (v == 3)
lt_4 = (v == 5)
lt_5 = (v == 0)
lt_6 = (v >= 0)
lt_7 = (v <= 4)

s_vars = [v]
e_vars = [a, b, c, d]
pos_lts = [lt_1, lt_2, lt_3, lt_4, lt_5, lt_6, lt_7]
neg_lts = []
posNeg_Conjunction = And(And(pos_lts), And(neg_lts))
universal = ForAll([e_vars], (posNeg_Conjunction))

pol_phi = Exists([s_vars], universal)
solve(pol_phi)
```

Note there is an empty list `neg_lts` (done on purpose).

Since universally quantified variables do not appear inside the formula (also done on purpose), I tested changing the last part of the code, just in case:

```
...
posNeg_Conjunction = And(And(pos_lts), And(neg_lts))
universal = posNeg_Conjunction

pol_phi = Exists([s_vars], universal)
solve(pol_phi)
```

But still get the same error (but now in the `Exists` part). Nothing changes, either, if I set the variables to `Reals`. So I do not know what boundaries is the error talking about.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a couple of typos here and there, which makes it hard to replicate. But bottom line, you need either a single-variable or a list of variables in the quantified position, and they all need to be declared beforehand. Fixing your other typos as well, the following goes through:

```py
from z3 import *

v, a, b, c, d, e = Ints('v a b c d e').

lt_1 = (v == 4)
lt_2 = (v == 2)
lt_3 = (v == 3)
lt_4 = (v == 5)
lt_5 = (v == 0)
lt_6 = (v >= 0)
lt_7 = (v <= 4)

s_vars = [v]
e_vars = [a, b, c, d]
pos_lts = [lt_1, lt_2, lt_3, lt_4, lt_5, lt_6, lt_7]
neg_lts = []
posNeg_Conjunction = And(And(pos_lts), And(neg_lts))
universal = ForAll(e_vars, (posNeg_Conjunction))

pol_phi = Exists(s_vars, universal)
solve(pol_phi)
```

When run, it prints `no solution`. I didn't try to understand your formulation so I'm guessing that's expected; your question seems to be mostly about how to write quantified formulae correctly in z3py.

Comment: Hello, sorry for that. I realized and corrected it, but you already answered hehe In any case, your formulation is correct except for `sys_vars`, which does not exist: it is just `s_vars`. Try putting `s_vars` after the `Exists`, don't you get the error? I still do.

Comment: Updated the answer; it goes through just fine for me.

Comment: Okay I get it. My problem was much more embarrassing: I was using `[ ]` for lists. I mean, your solution is correct, but just replace `sys_vars` with `s_vars` and do not use the `[ ]`. I do not know how I missed that. Sorry for making you loose your time :( Still I can ask: does `no solution` mean the validity is false?

Comment: Note that the first argument to `ForAll` (or `Exists`) is either a list of variables, or a single-variable. By wrapping up `[s_vars]`, you're making it a list of list of variables, which isn't syntactically meaningful in that context.

Comment: No worries. Unfortunately the Python bindings are very loose in what they accept and what they don't; and they aren't always consistent. So, these sorts of mistakes are very hard to spot.