# Z3-Python: Invalid bounded variables strikes back with Complex numbers

Tags: python, list, z3, z3py, theorem-proving

Using Z3 (in Python), the `Z3Exception: Invalid bounded variable(s)` error (same as asked in [Z3: Invalid bounded variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086689/z3-invalid-bounded-variables)) strikes back. But with a different shape, I guess.

It happens, concretely, when using the codification of Complex numbers by de Moura in (https://leodemoura.github.io/blog/2013/01/26/complex.html). We can see it below:

```
x = Complex('x')
y = Complex('y')
vars = [x,y]

l_1 = (-1000.5 == x*x)
l_2 = (y == x)

phi = Implies(l_1, l_2)

solve(Exists([x], (x==1)))
```

It returns the error on the last line.

The problem has nothing to do with `l_1`, nor `l_2` (nor with `vars`), since it also fails for this:

```
x = Complex('x')

solve(Exists([x], (x==1)))
```

If I **only** change the type of the variable, it returns `[]` with no problem:

```
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
vars = [x,y]

l_1 = (-1000.5 == x*x)
l_2 = (y == x)

phi = Implies(l_1, l_2)

solve(Exists([x], And(l_1, l_2)))
```

Thus, there is a problem with the encoding of Complex and not with lists as it was in [Z3: Invalid bounded variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086689/z3-invalid-bounded-variables)

Any idea?

**EDIT**

Trying the answer for a list of variables:

```
def ComplexExists(ls, phi):
  existential_ls = []
  for i in range(0, len(ls)):
    existential_ls.append([ls[i].r, ls[i].i])
  print(existential_ls)
  return Exists(existential_ls, phi)

x = Complex('x')
y = Complex('y')
vars = [x,y]

l_1 = (-1000.5 == x*x)
l_2 = (y == x)

phi = Implies(l_1, l_2)

solve(ComplexExists(vars, phi))
```

Same error. Obviously. The ComplexExists returns a list like: `[[x.r, x.i], [y.r, y.i], ...]`

This is the other alternative:

```
def ComplexExists(ls, phi):
  existential_ls = []
  for i in range(0, len(ls)):
    existential_ls.append(ls[i].r)
    existential_ls.append(ls[i].i)
  print(existential_ls)
  return Exists(existential_ls, phi)
```

It returns a single list and works, but all the variables (both real parts and imaginary) are part of the same list, which sounds strange: `[x.r, x.i, y.r, y.i, ...]`

Comment: Added a version of `ComplexExists` to my answer that can handle a list of complex variables. Hope that does the trick for you.

Comment: Note that your second solution to `ComplexExists` works correctly, and how this function should work. There's no problem having all those variables in the same list; in fact, that's required. (You can also nest the quantifiers, but I think that's an overkill.) My solution is similar, except written in more succinct Python code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that z3 has no knowledge of the `Complex` class; so when it tries to create the quantified expression it fails to map them to proper internal values.

The solution is easy; simply make sure to tell z3 about which "base" variables you're quantifying over. That is, instead of:

```py
solve(Exists([x], And(l_1, l_2)))
```

Use:

```py
solve(Exists([x.r, x.i], (x==1)))
```

Alternatively, you can define:

```py
def ComplexExists(cv, e):
    return Exists([cv.r, cv.i], e)
```

And then:

```py
solve(ComplexExists(x, x==1))
```

You can create variants of `ComplexExists` that handles a list as its first argument, like z3's `Exists` method does; etc.

Note that you get an empty list as your model when you run it because the only thing you asserted is locally quantified; and thus you don't have any "top-level" variables to show the values of. I'd rather code it like this:

```py
s = Solver()
s.add(Exists([x.r, x.i], (x==1)))
s.add(phi)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Then you get:

```
sat
[x.r = 0, y.r = 0, x.i = 0, y.i = 0]
```

Now the output is clear. (Note that the model doesn't satisfy your locally quantified existential, because that `x` is *different* than the top-level `x`; and since `phi` is an implication, it satisfies that by making the antecedent false.`)

### Making `ComplexExists` work for a list of variables

Here's a version of `ComplexExists` that takes a list of complex numbers:

```py
def ComplexExists(ls, phi):
    return Exists([qv for v in ls for qv in [v.r, v.i]], phi)
```

With this definition, you can call:

```py
solve(ComplexExists(vars, phi))
```

and it should work just fine.

Comment: Hello, you completely (as always) got my problem! I am now trying to program ComplexExists to receive a list of variables (see the edition of the question) and still have some problems. Obviously, it does fail, since I am giving a list of lists `[[x.r, x.i]]`. I do it in case I would like to give the algorithm, for instance, `x` and `y`, then: `[[x.r, x.i], [y.r, y.i]]`. However, it seems it does not make sense. Do I have to give these numbers in a single list like: `[x.r, x.i, y.r, y.i]`? Does this make sense? I mean, it does, if we consider complex numbers as tuples, does it?

Comment: You’d have to program the function differently to handle list and variable cases. Unless this is of utmost importance, I’d recommend not worrying about it. Otherwise, study the z3py’s own implementation to see how it handles variables and lists. You’ll have to do something similar.